# Не работает цикл в цикле

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть код

```
ip_form = open("ip_form.txt", encoding="utf-8")
new_file = open("form.txt", "wt", encoding="utf-8")
numbe = "1234567890."
ip = list()

for ip_for in ip_form.read():
    if ip_for in numbe:
        print('1')
        if len(ip) >= 7:
            for ip_for in ip_form.read():
                print('2222222222222222')
                if ip_for in numbe:
                    ip.append(ip_for)
                else:
                    write = ''.join(ip)
                    new_file.write(write)
                    ip.clear()
                    print('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&')
                    break
            print('?????')
        if ip_for in numbe:
            ip.append(ip_form)
    else:
        ip.clear()
        print('33333333333')
```

(print нужен просто для проверки), ошибку не выдает, но и не работает `for ip_for in ip_form.read():`, просто не заходит на этот цикл. Спасибо всем кто подскажет, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Странно. Должно заходить, но перебирать ваш код содержимое файла будет по одному символу. Попробуйте присвоить `ip_form.read()` в отдельную переменную и напечатайте её, а цикл сделайте уже по содержанию этой переменной. И внутри цикла сразу сделайте `print(ip_for)`.

Comment: Два вложенных цикла по одному файлу. Второй цикл не исполняется. Никогда не накапливатеся семь цифр. Нет вывода. Пройдитесь по коду с отладчиком.

Comment: А, точно. Что внутри такой же цикл я не заметил ))  Файл уже весь прочитан, второй цикл исполняться не будет.

Comment: не нужно задавать один и тот же вопрос два раза